# HTTP download not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my Rails controller:

```
  def download_clip
    send_file "public/output.mp4", :type=>"video/mp4", :filename => "output.mp4", :disposition => 'attachment'
  end
```

and in my HTML code I have this:

```
<a href="download_clip/"></a>
```

Now could somebody tell me why Firefox's download window will NOT pou up, but chrome downloads the file fine? Instead firefox opens a new window and starts playing the file. I WANT THE DOWNLOAD BOX to POPUP. I have spend too much time on it

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative url, which may not map correctly depending on the page it is used.

Try changing your link to:

```
<%= link_to "some text", :controller => :your_controller_name, :action => :download_clip %>
```

If this doesn't help, check if the Content-Diposition response header is being set as 'attachment'.  If it is, then the problem is likely with your own Firefox environment and not with the server.  Resetting Firefox to defaults should fix that...

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;"
```

in your download_clip action..

Comment: I believe that `send_file` does this already if you pass `:disposition => 'attachment'` as the OP has...